# Slow internet with Asus DSL-N17U

Tags: connection, adsl

I have two DSL routers with same configuration (I think so) , one is TECHNICOLOR TD5130 V2 (provided by the ISP Maroc Telecom) and the other one is Asus DSL-N17U which I bought to use the nice features.
I pay for a 12Mbps / 1 Mbps, when I do a speed test with the TECHNICOLOR I easily get 10 Mbps but with Asus I only get 6Mbps, both test after a reset and a firmware update using a wired connection trough my PC.
Also I noticed that get different data rate for each router with same cable in the same splitter socket

```
Asus : 9 152 Kbps
Technicolor: 12 495 Kbps
```

could you please help solve this issue to use the Asus router and get the correct speed?

Comment: Your Tecnicolor modem/router will have been preconfigured by your ISP to have the optimal settings such as how it deals with the DSL signal, additionally, your ISP will do line testing to work out line quality and potentially update your modem/router remotely (if it's the Tecnicolor). You may not have configured the Asus with the optimal settings so, although it authenticates and you get internet, the signal may not be optimal so you're getting the best speed.

Comment: could you suggest what should I be looking for to copy the config from?

Comment: Go through all the Tecnicolr DSL settings - such as MTU, VCU etc and make sure the same settings are applied to the Asus. Trial and error. Alternatively, you could just connect the Asus (using the "Cable/DSL port" using a patch lead) to the Tecnicolor LAN and turn off the likes of wireless and DHCP on the Tecnicolor so that your Asus uses the Tecnicolor just for the Internet, but your LAN uses the Asus.

Comment: Most modems firmware are locked down.  Even when you purchase your own modem, you often cannot update it and are left at the mercy of your ISP to remotely update it.  In the end, there are very few DSL modem manufactures.  Most of them only provide their firmware to business class customers (ISPs) anyways.  I would contact your ISP for assistance.

Comment: the ISP is extremely unresponsive, no hope , the only solution is to find the correct config